# Is "clique" a subgraph or a vertex subset?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

The concept of **clique** is commonly encountered in graph theory. However, while I was looking at the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)) today, I found it a bit ambiguous.

> In the mathematical area of graph theory, a *clique*  is **a subset of**
> **vertices** of an undirected graph such that every two distinct vertices
> in the clique are adjacent. That is, a clique of a graph $G$ is an
> **induced subgraph** of  $G$ that is complete.

We know that the concepts of vertex subsets and induced subgraphs are entirely different. I have consulted various books such as textbooks by Bondy and West, as well as the "Handbook of Graph Theory," which predominantly refer to the former, i.e., a clique in $G$ is a set of vertices of $G$, all pairwise adjacent.

However, the latter term also is commonly used; see:

- https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Clique.html
- see Page 10 of " Fundamentals of Graph Theory, Allan Bickle. " It says: "A clique is a complete subgraph, or the set of vertices inducing a complete subgraph."

It seems that there shouldn't be ambiguity around the common concept, but I'm unsure why there is a difference in definitions.

Which of these concepts is preferable or more accurate is unclear.

Comment: It is a matter of convetion between the reader and writer and virtually impossible to get into a misunderstanding over it in a concrete situation.

Comment: "We know that the concepts of vertex subsets and induced subgraphs are entirely different". Not so much: a vertex subset uniquely defines an induced subgraph, and an induced subgraph is uniquely determined by its vertices. So they are formally different things, but quite interchangable.

Comment: They are different concepts because a graph with vertices from some set $V$ has more structure than the set $V$ itself.. In informal settings, it is common enough to implicitly apply some "forgetful functor" (e.g. when we treat a group as its underlying set). I'd say go with the most convenient definition, the one used by the book you're currently working with etc

Comment: For any subset of vertices of undirected graph $G$ there is precisely one [induced subgraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_subgraph) of $G$ with those vertices. So, there is bijection between subsets of vertices of $G$ and induced subgraphs of $G$. Therefore, you can identify subsets of vertices of $G$ and induced subgraphs of $G$, so it doesn't really matter if you choose clique to be subset of vertices or induced subgraph, the only thing that matters is that the corresponding induced subgraph is complete as graph.

Comment: I'd also say that the (first) formulation in Wikipedia is a bit unfortunate. More consistent would be 'That is, a clique of a graph G is a subset of its vertices whose induced subgraph is complete'. A similar formulation is used in the Definitions section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some authors use existing definitions, some authors change it a bit, and some others give completely different meaning to the existing terms and notations. That's why we may have different formal definitions of essentially the same stuff.

Duality between a set (sequence) of vertices and a subgraph appears in other parts of graph theory too, as well as between other formally different objects.

In case of cliques there is only formal, but not an essential difference between a pairwise adjacent vertex set and a complete subgraph, because there is bijection between such sets and such subgraphs. The same holds for any other vertex set and corresponding induced subgraph.

For example components. Usually a *component* is defined as a maximal connected subgraph. However some authors consider a component as a maximal pairwise connected vertex set.

Another example is a walk. According to Bondy and Murty, *walk* is a finite non-null sequence $W = v_0e_1v_1e_2v_2\ldots e_kv_k$, whose terms are alternately vertices and edges [...], and $W$ is called a *path* if the vertices $v_0, v_1, \ldots, v_k$ are distinct. For a simple graph it is possible to white only vertices of the walk, because all edges of the walk are defined by these vertices. Also if one defines walk as a sequence of vertices there is no essential difference for simple graph in spite of this sequence is different from the first one. But for a path it is also possible to define it as a (not induced) subgraph. Here difference is a bit more essential, because paths $v_0v_1\ldots v_k$ and $v_kv_{k - 1}\ldots v_0$ correspond to the same subgraph. However we can't consider a walk as a subgraph, because it may contain a vertex or an edge multiple times, while subgraph can't reflect this multiple usage precisely, and the direction of passing the subcycles of the walk.

Similar stuff happens to a *cycle*, which is defined as a closed walk, whose origin and internal vertices are distinct. On the other hand, it can be considered as a $2$-regular connected subgraph, however one such subgraph corresponds to $2k$ vertex sequences, which describe essentially the same cycle.

*Cut* may be defined as a set of edges, removing which from the graph leads to a disconnected graph. But it is also sometimes defined as a partition of vertex set of the graph into two subsets. Here we have essential difference, because the first definition allows diconnecting the graph into more than $2$ parts.

I guess this list can be continued infinitely. Similarly letter $V$ usually means a vertex set, however more and more people use this letter for the number of vertices (instead of $|V|$).

If you ask what is correct about cliques, then the best answer would be that the correct definition for a certain textbook or article is given in this textbook or article. The quoted Wikipedia article is inconsistent, because different people make lots of small changes and sometimes don't care about consistency within the whole article. On the other hand, if you write your own article I would recommend to define clique as a vertex set.